# Can a 0.1mm iron cannonball fired with a proportional cannon damage a tumbler (glass)?

Tags: mass, home-experiment, mass-energy, density

A teammate just used the well known phrase "a storm in a teacup".
I looked at my tumbler (full of water) and asked this question:

"If a pirate ship the size of a nutshell had cannons with iron cannonballs with a diameter of 0.1 mm, can it damage the (glass) tumbler with it's cannonballs?"

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are talking about but I sense that it is not about physics.

Comment: I am pretty sure that other people understand what I am talking about and I got two very good anwers.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have not specified the "real world" size of the ship, let's take a 74-gun ship of the line https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventy-four_(ship) as the desired type, firing a 36-pound cannon. The bore on such a cannon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/36-pounder_long_gun was about 175 mm, with a shot weight of about 39 lb.

Shrinking this cannon to a bore of 0.1 mm involves a scale reduction of 1750 to 1. Since a 74 was typically about 160 to 180 feet long, this suggests a teacup-ship about 1 inch long, which seems reasonable.

EDIT - Per Floris' comment, I'll point out that you have also not specified what a "proportional cannon" means in terms of muzzle velocity. I have simply assumed that "proportional" means proportional to length. If you wish a different type of proportionality, please specify it. END EDIT

Then the 450 m/s muzzle velocity of a 36-pound cannon scales to .25 m/sec, or a tad over 1/2 mile per hour. As a handy comparison, this is the equivalent of dropping the shot from a distance of 3 mm.

So, no, it really doesn't seem likely that your ship can shoot its way out of a teacup.

Comment: I am not sure velocity scales linearly with the size of the object... since the mass of the ball goes down as the cube of the size, but the area (force) as the square. Then there is the mass of the explosive charge and the volume it expands into... but the conclusion is almost certainly correct (and the "handy comparison" is awesome).

Comment: @Floris - Yeah, I suppose I should edit. The question simply referred to a "proportional cannon".

Comment: Two great anwers - hard to choose the correct one. Any chance to combine them?

Answer (score 1):

**Short:**  No

**Because:**

Assume material SG ~= 7
Assume ~= non-sonic shot. Say 500 m/S based on [**this superb reference**](http://arc.id.au/CannonBallistics.html)
R = 0.05mm = 5E-5m
E= 1/2 mV^2

m kg = 4/3.Pi.R^3 x sg  x 1000 kg/m^3
= 4/3x 3.14 x (5E-5)^3 x 1000 x 7 = 3.E-9 kg
At say V = 500 m/s
E = 0.5 x 3.5E-9 x 500^2 ~~= 500 micro Joule.    (438 uJ calc)

A VERY solid teaspoon weighs 50 gram.
Energy when dropped = mgh so
h = E/mg.
50 gram teaspoon drop height for 500 uJ
= 500E-6/10/0.050 = 0.001m
= 1 mm

Any glass that will break when a 50 gram teaspoon was dropped 1 mm into it would also break when you breathed on it.

So, no.

E&OE but no anyway :-).

---

Notes:

Due to comments by WhatRoughBeast.

I changed SG from 10 to 7 and remembered to use it where I should have.

I changed muzzle velocity from 300 m/s to 500 m/s based on the maximum value from the utterly superb [**Smooth Bore Cannon Ballistics**](http://arc.id.au/CannonBallistics.html) page. I suspect that this is high as, using gun powder muzzle velocity will not scale down with size but cube-square law will reduce powder charge per area appreciably. Also, there is an empirical figure in the formula which allows for "windage" and this is liable to be a smaller figure for the scaled down gun.

Floris notes that impulse rather than energy is the better metric for impact damage. I take her point but would not be certain which is in fact better and it's probably some somewhat complex tradeoff depending on target material, rigidity of impact area etc. eg a cannon ball that entangles rigging is probably energy dominant, and the (utterly horrific) lengthwise raking of a ship by a Nelson style crossing the line of ships arranged to deliver broadsides, probably values impulse for initial splintering effect and  shot energy for progress along the internal deck.
One (I at least) tend to forget what a horrid subject this is until the details of what "better" mean start to come to mind. An exercise worth doing occasionally, alas :-(. Hopefully no micro-sailors would be harmed by the micro-Joule shot energies involved here. (I'll not start to calculate that but I rather suspect it's not true). (Ballistic range would be shortened by square-cube effects).

Comment: I imagine this may be deemed engineering :-). If so, mayhaps it should be moved there.

Comment: Note it is NOT the energy, but the momentum of the cannonball that would do the damage (local force / pressure). Sand grains hitting glass will cut it (sand blasting). Two other points: "mayhaps" - awesome word. And may I recommend that you [read up on the use of MathJax on the SE sites](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)? It allows for much "prettier" (and in many cases, more readable) typesetting.

Comment: Two great anwers - hard to choose the correct one. Any chance to combine them?

Comment: As a quibble, you forgot to include specific gravity numbers (~7), and per the Wiki site I linked, muzzle velocity was about 50% higher than you're using. Total change is a factor of about 15. Teaspoon drop height goes to about .2 mm. Big deal.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast THanks. Changes and additions made. I think muzzle velocity will not scale down linearly (see answer) and/but there are scaling effects due to square/cube effects. Also see superb smooth bore velocity page.

Comment: Also, if scaling completely breaks down and muzzle velocity remains at 400 - 500 m/sec, I suspect that the cup will not survive. BB guns, with a larger (4+ mm) ball but lower (100 m/sec for kid's guns) muzzle velocity will commonly punch out a cone of glass from a window. (If you do stained glass, you can use this to produce cabochon "gems" from plate glass.) So for high velocities I'm not quite sure what the actual result for a much smaller ball will be.